# pointer being freed was not allocated in C

Tags: c, clang

Not sure what is wrong with the code below and why it is giving me the error "pointer being freed was not allocated". Using clang.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char * messagePtr;

int main()
{

    messagePtr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 800);
    if(messagePtr == NULL) {
       printf("Bad malloc error\n");
       exit(1);
    }


    // //gameLoop();
    char outputMessage[50] = "";
    messagePtr = outputMessage;

    free(messagePtr);
    messagePtr = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `messagePtr = outputMessage;` = no longer pointing to the (now leaked) dynamic memory you allocated earlier. If you don't see that, you need to review the section on dynamic memory management in whatever book or tutorial you're using.

Comment: You do not need the cast for `malloc` in C - better it is removed

Comment: Keep that in mind: You don't "free a pointer", you free the memory it **points to**! (I'd really like to have a serious talk with teachers who spread such nonsense - would greatly reduce confusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned `outputMessage`, which is an array and is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array, to `messagePtr`, so `messagePtr` no longer points at what is allcated via `malloc()` or its family.

Passing what is not `NULL` and is not allocated via memory management functions such as `malloc()` invokes *undefined behavior*. ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.22.3.3 The free function)

Note that they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Some of your options are:

1. Stop using `malloc()` for allocating buffer that will be thrown away.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char * messagePtr;

int main()
{

    // //gameLoop();
    char outputMessage[50] = "";
    messagePtr = outputMessage;

    messagePtr = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

2. Free the buffer *before* throwing it away.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char * messagePtr;

int main()
{

    messagePtr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 800);
    if(messagePtr == NULL) {
       printf("Bad malloc error\n");
       exit(1);
    }


    // //gameLoop();
    free(messagePtr);
    char outputMessage[50] = "";
    messagePtr = outputMessage;

    messagePtr = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

3. Use `strcpy()` to copy strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char * messagePtr;

int main()
{

    messagePtr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 800);
    if(messagePtr == NULL) {
       printf("Bad malloc error\n");
       exit(1);
    }


    // //gameLoop();
    char outputMessage[50] = "";
    strcpy(messagePtr, outputMessage);

    free(messagePtr);
    messagePtr = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strcpy() was the function that I was looking for. I had looked at a lot of tutorials, searched a lot on the web and here and figured that the solution was probably simple, I just wasn't finding it. Thank you everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

The lines

```
char outputMessage[50] = "";
messagePtr = outputMessage;
```

create a `char[50]` and assign `messagePtr` the address of that array, thus **removing the pointer to the** `malloc`**ed memory**. The successive `free` call therefore tries to free `messagePtr`, not the memory allocated by `malloc`. Not only this, the `malloc`ated memory will be lost since you have lost all reference (i.e., the pointer) to it.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish by `messagePtr = outputMessage`, so I can't really give you a hint on solving this - except to **not reassign a pointer returned by** `malloc` **prior to** `free`**ing it**.

---

Notes:

- You do not need to cast `void*`, as returned by `malloc`, to other pointer types. There is an implicit conversion for that. Read [why not to cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

```
messagePtr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 800);
```

makes messagePtr pointing to the location in Heap where malloc allocated 800 chars (e.g. 1005). This location has to be freed.

```
messagePtr = outputMessage;
```

makes messagePtr pointing to the location in Stack where 50 chars where automatically allocated (e.g. 505).

Automatic allocations can not be freed with free. They are deallocated automatically when the variable's scope ends.
Calling free on the automatically allocated memory is an error. free has to be called on location 1005 (according to the example).